# Add multiple images on Canvas with Kineticjs

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I was going through HTML5 Canvas Kinteticjs [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-image-tutorial/) for adding image. I want to add multiple images and layer them.
The example below has two images but both are the same.

The question: How do i load 2 different images?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create two image objects instead of one, and on load of both, you can put both images onto the canvas.

```
var imgObj1 = new Image();
var imgObj2 = new Image();
var loadCount = 0;

imgObj1.onload = function() {
   loadCount++;
   if(loadCount==2) putOnCanvas();
};

imgObj2.onload = function() {
   loadCount++;
   if(loadCount==2) putOnCanvas();
};

imgObj1.src = ".....";
imgObj2.src = ".....";

function putOnCanvas() {
    var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 140,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 59,
      image: imageObj1,
      width: 106,
      height: 118
    });

    var filteredYoda = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 320,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 59,
      image: imageObj2,
      width: 106,
      height: 118
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(yoda);
    layer.add(filteredYoda);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);

    // apply grayscale filter to second image
    filteredYoda.applyFilter(Kinetic.Filters.Grayscale, null, function() {
      layer.draw();
    });
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a more eloquent way? Imagine you want to create a game and have to load all images. This way I would end up with hundreds of lines for only the onload functions.

Comment: You could do something like "imageObj.onload = function() { stage.batchDraw(); }" for every Image object, but this will render empty images until they're fully loaded. Best solution would be to preload them all or make some kind of wrapper that takes care of things. If it's a game, you're not going to keep on reloading images all the time - that would be too laggy.

Answer (score 1):

As you may already know, Image is not a KineticJS object, but Kinetic.Image is.

So, as long as you make  one-to-one connection between Image and Kinetic.Image, you are ok with it.

The example on the html5canvastutorials.com uses Image.onload function to create Kinetic.Image. This confuses so many people. However you don't need to do that if you preload images.

The purpose of creating Kinetic.Image when Image is loaded is not to have invalid(broken) images on canvas. So, if you make all you Images valid, by preloading those, you don't need to use image.onload, which make you confused, at all.

To preload iamges,

1. you can simply add images to your document and make it as hidden
2. Or, call image url using ajax call.